# Descargar múltiples ficheros en IONIC con plugin nativo FTP

Tags: ionic, plugin, ftp

alguien puede orientarme sobre cómo descargar varios ficheros con el plugin nativo de FTP ??...
El método download devuelve un observable con el porcentaje finalizado, pero no se como esperar a que acabe uno, para que siga con el siguiente...
He probado con un do while, pero tampoco funciona...

"localFile" y "remoteFile" son elementos del array de ficheros a transferir....

> ```
>   this._ftp.download(localFile, remoteFile).subscribe( (value) => {
>       if ( value == 1) 
>         { console.log ( "finalizado !"); }
>       else
>         { console.log ( value * 100 , " % completado..."); } 
>  });
> ```

Gracias !!